# Where have my Panel Applets gone in Natty?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, panel

#### This *might* be a bug but it might just be an undocumented "feature". I'm asking because I want to know.

**Edit:** This is now also [filed as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/765794).

**Edit:** Here's a [strace of gnome-panel](http://paste.ubuntu.com/600576/).

Upgraded to Natty from Maverick today with the intention of keeping my panel-based Gnome2 setup. I've already asked if that's possible and it does appear that's the case.

My problem is on loading the panels, I get a ton of errors from very default applets like the Window list, Notification Area and Clock. Upon further investigation, I don't appear to be able to even add these types of applet. They're missing from the Add to Panel dialogue.

### Is there a package I need to install to get these applets back?

Here's what I see on boot:

[image: Argl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this has been an adventure. I had seen [this MintForum thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=70829&p=411459) before but ignored it mainly because it was talking about `bonobo` (which is frankly a silly word) but also because the applet in discussion was the MintMenu.

I decided to go back there today and actually read it. [plumm's post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=70829&p=411459#p411410) has given me a few clues and has actually got a few things working (after some modification). Here's what I'm doing. Until I've got everything back this post is a work in progress.

First you have to locate your `bonobo-activation-config` file:

```
# locate bonobo-activation-config
/etc/bonobo-activation/bonobo-activation-config.xml
```

Then we find where all the applets' bonobo-server-item-configuration files are:

```
# locate bonobo/server | grep GNOME
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_BrightnessApplet.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_DictionaryApplet.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_GtikApplet.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_InhibitApplet.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_Magnifier.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_Moniker_std.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_SeahorseApplet.server
/usr/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_TSClientApplet.server
/usr/local/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_ClockApplet_Factory.server
/usr/local/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_FishApplet_Factory.server
/usr/local/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_NotificationAreaApplet.server
/usr/local/lib/bonobo/servers/GNOME_Wncklet_Factory.server
```

Then we put the two together, creating new xml `<items>` in the `bonobo-activation-config.xml`. We only need the common path so there are only two things to carry. Here's my finished file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<oafconfig>

<searchpath>
    <item>/usr/lib/bonobo/servers</item>
    <item>/usr/local/lib/bonobo/servers</item>
</searchpath>

</oafconfig>
```

After a restart everything but `GNOME_ClockApplet` has loaded back up.

More on this when I've fixed it.

Comment: I had this exact same problem. Thank you for your partial fix. Did you figure out how to enable the Gnome Clock Applet? My Indicator applets are also nowhere to be found...

Answer (score 0):

Well..there is a big issue here. Upgrading from maverick to natty is not going to be easy I must say! I have had the exact same issues as you are having . Try and follow these steps and see if it helps.

1. Logout and login to the ubuntu classic session instead of unity.
2. Open up synapic / software-centre/ terminal and remove all indicator applets

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove indicator-applets*
   ```
3. then logout and log back in.

Now you will be able to see the gnome panels. Then you can add the existing applets
If you cannot live without the ubuntu indicator applets try re-installing them. They have been causing errors for me in the gnome classic session. so i got rid of them.

Right now, i have a situation where even unity is creating a lot of issues for me. i am thinking of installing gnome 3 and check how it fares. if everything fails i will have to do a clean install.

Comment: No help I'm afraid. Removed all Indicator Applets (which unnervingly also removes `ubuntu-desktop`), restarted and same errors. I do get my panels, my on-panel launchers and Cardapio  (albeit broken), but no other applets.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is a meta package which identifies ubuntu as a distribution. it does not affect your system. but, now that you have got your panels, you can add your applets one by one by right clicking on the top panel and selecting add to panel. if you can install docky and update the cardapio ppa and update the system. see what you get. the other idea that i can give you is create a test account and see how it behaves when you log into that account.

Comment: ok. now i have my gnome2.32 classic desktop with cardapio, docky and the indicator applets all set. took me an hour to set it right. after removing all the indicator applets i restarted my system. then logging into the terminal using ctrl+alt+f1, i issued the follwoing command:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop. Remember, if you have any application from maverick which you think is conflicting with your new installation, just remove it. you can install it later on.

Comment: I don't think removing indicator applets is a good idea. Removing ubuntu-desktop and then installing it again may help in pulling in missed recommended packages.