# How can I debug panel applets?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, debugging

So I've got [an issue with Natty's Gnome 2 panels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35905/where-have-my-panel-applets-gone-in-natty). Short story: most of the panel applets are either missing or crashing out. Something's unhappy and I can't work out what or why.

#### So how do you get debugging information from a gnome-panel and its applets?

Is there a log file somewhere, or a method of starting it so that it does leave a log file?

Comment: I had a similar problem that magically went away after removing `~/.cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can run the panel from a terminal, so any informational output is displayed in the terminal (or you could redirect it to a file, using shell redirection).

   ```
   $ # replace extant panel
   $ gnome-panel --replace
   ```
2. You can run applets from the command line as well. First, remove from the panel, then run the applet binary (perhaps having first used 'ps' prior to removal to see what the binary is). Once you've started the binary, then use the panel "Add to panel..." to run it. Its output will then be displayed in the terminal. You can also run applets using gdb in this way.